# JLabel should not be able to receive focus.. but it does?

Tags: java, swing, focusmanager

I'm working on a Swing application that uses the default Swing methods for handling focus.  Focus isn't working as I'd expect.

In one case, I have a JTextField that I call .requestFocusInWindow()  When the window is displayed a JLabel has focus instead

The Java 6 docs for JLabel say  "As a result, it cannot get the keyboard focus."  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html

However, I have a sample application that shows a JLabel receiving focus and KeyboardFocusManager.getFocusOwner() returns that component.  (http://github.com/akinsgre/swingStarter)

The code the the class is https://raw.github.com/akinsgre/swingStarter/master/src/main/java/test/HelloWorldSwing.java

Can anyone help me understand or explain what I'm missing?

Comment: most of us not going to the unknow_depots, and for future readers especially, for better help sooner edit your question with an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), JLabel and one of focusable JComponent e.g. JTextField with demonstrating your Focus and Focusable

Comment: No idea why the JLabel would receive focus but a suggestion for your other problem. The javadoc for [requestFocus()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#requestFocus(boolean)) recommends to not use that method as it is platform dependent and to use [requestFocusInWindow()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#requestFocusInWindow()) whenever possible.

Comment: mKorbel:  I thought I was doing that.  The Github repo (unknown?) is a maven project, with a Single class file.  But.. OK.  The class file is here  https://raw.github.com/akinsgre/swingStarter/master/src/main/java/test/HelloWorldSwing.java (and isn't a link to the source better than pasting the code inline)?

Comment: Thanks Danny.  I use requestFocusInWindow in the source.  But that doesn't give me any different results.

Comment: *"I have a JTextField that I call .requestFocus()"*  That is not what is suggested by the line in `HelloWorldSwing` that states `label.requestFocusInWindow();`

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to associate the label with the text field.  So try using the setLabelFor method and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks Bill That doesn't change the behavior.  The JLabel still can have Focus.   I can avoid the problem by using setFocusable(false).. that still doesn't clear up why the docs seem to disagree with behavior of the JLabel